# What are these flitting sea worms?

Tags: species-identification, marine-biology

I filmed the creatures below this August in the Mediterranean (specifically, the port of [Fornells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fornells,_Minorca) in Minorca of the Balleares). The images were taken from a boat moored just outside the harbor and floating above a field of [posidonia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posidonia_oceanica) in case that is relevant.

There were *many* of them and they were whizzing about at high speed:

[image]
[image]

This is to give you an idea of the scale. The jellyfish on the right was about the size of half a tennis ball.

[image]

They were a very strange sight since there were so many of them and moving so fast. You can see a video of them in motion here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJCzjXALRJ0

The image quality is not very good but you can see how fast the things were moving. So, any idea what these are? I am assuming they are larvae of something or other but what?